# Capture network traffic using fiddler in Window Subsystem for Android (WSA)

Tags: android, windows, adb, fiddler, windows-subsystem-for-android

Fiddler is not capturing network traffic of WSA. I want to set proxy in WSA so I can capture network traffic in fiddler, also before setting proxy in WSA, I also need to install Telerik Fiddler Certificate in WSA, how can I do this?

- I tried enabling **Advanced Networking** option in WSA but it didn't worked and network stopped working in WSA
- I also googled for how can I set proxy using **adb** but did not find anything

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See the commands at https://gist.github.com/rlaphoenix/f8552a16fcd961a133583105710bfb68 for how to add a proxy root CA certificate as system certificate to WSA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows PowerShell, enter:

```
ifconfig
```

And note the `IPV4 Address` of the first `Ethernet adapter vEthernet`:
[image: Ethernet adapter vEthernet]

Go to Fiddler in **Tools > Options > Connections** and note the port on which it listens to (usually 8888)

#### To add the proxy to the settings via **adb**

First enable the `Developer mode` in WSA **Advanced settings**.

Then you can connect to the WSA using **adb** (assuming you have **adb** installed):

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1:58526
```

Finally run those commands to configure the proxy:

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8888
adb shell settings put global global_http_proxy_host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
adb shell settings put global global_http_proxy_port 8888
adb shell reboot
```

with `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` being the IPV4 Address you previously noted.

To remove the proxy, just run those commands:

```
adb shell settings delete global http_proxy
adb shell settings delete global global_http_proxy_host
adb shell settings delete global global_http_proxy_port
adb shell reboot
```

#### To add the proxy in the Android settings menu

You can also configure the proxy in the settings menu.
You still need **adb** however, as I didn't find any other way to open WSA android settings other than running:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings
```

There you can open **Network & internet > Internet > VirtWifi**. Modify it, the interface of the popup is a bit buggy on my side; you might have to navigate through the fields with the TAB key.

Set **Proxy** to `Manual`, **Proxy hostname** to the IPV4 Address, and **Proxy port** to the Fiddler port.

Don't forget to hit save after that.

NB: Since we are in the Android settings, we can also set the CA Certificate of Fiddler to sniff HTTPS packet. For that, you can follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@roy2477/decrypting-android-app-ssl-traffic-c480e2143743)